# django query for sorting the data on a field present as foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```
class abc(xyz):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=100)
```

What'll be the django query for sorting the data based on a foreign key field?

I tried with query:

```
  abc.objects.filter(User__user=user).
  abc.objects.filter(Q(user__icontains=search_query) ).
```

I have done this 2 queries, But dont know how to combine & make it work

I don't know how to proceed. Can someone please lend a helping hand?

Comment: Your query and heading don't match. What do you mean by combine? Do you want to combine by 'OR' or 'AND'?

Comment: I want to sort based on "user" field which is a foreign key to my current model

Comment: is that correct that you want to combine(and/or) those two queries (which work well) and also sort the result? or something more?

Answer (score 1):

The first query does not work with your model. Change it to

```
qs = abc.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Now, sorting this queryset by `user` (or `user_id` or any other `user`'s property which would work)

```
qs = qs.order_by('user_id')
```

wouldn't make much sense as all elements in your queryset have the same user.

The second query does not work since `icontains` is a query that works for strings whereas `user` is a model instance. The following might work:

```
 abc.objects.filter(user__username__icontains=search_query)  # .order_by('user__username')
```

Generally, you can order by properties that have a (natural) order, like ints, floats, strings, dates, etc. Thus, you can order by sth. like `user_id`, `user__username`, `user__email`, `user__date_joined`:

```
abc.objects.all().order_by('user_id')  # for instance
```

Comment: Just forget my Django Query? Can you please tell me what ll be the query
for sorting the data on a particular field which itself is a foreign key?

please see my model class example in Question.

Comment: I updated my answer: usually you cannot directly sort by the ForeignKey field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to sort by user's username. You can do it by:

```
abc.objects.all().order_by('user__username')
```

Look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) for details.

Note the double underscore '__' here. It is required to separate the foreignkey's field from foreignkey by double underscore while referring foreignkey's field.

Comment: I want to sort by user field present as column in DB.
 abc.objects.filter(User__abc_user=user, Q(user__icontains=search_query)).

Will above work?

Comment: Then it means you want to sort by user's id. It should work:  abc.objects.all().order_by('user')

Comment: This is the way to sort by user's id: abc.objects.all().order_by('user__id'). Here, 'id' field is in the 'User' model. So need double underscore '__'. 'user__id' means 'id' field of 'User' model.